# Completely Remove All Versions of Java Silently (Ivanti) not dependant on machine install files-need it gone asap

Tags: windows-10, java

Tried Java newer uninstall utility, not working properly, basic script, now looking into uninstall reg key....  This is an enterprise removal need, looking for script WMI call etc... to package and execute on all 1600 + endpoints silently using Ivanti EPM (like SCCM).  Any assistance is appreciated.  Researching

Comment: Please careful and accurately list the precise steps you have tried so far. Just listing bullet points does not actually tell us what you've actually done. Next, tell us clearly what happened in each case, with error logs and any other data that may help us see WHY they failed. Finally, use proper or at least clear grammar, punctuation, and formatting, to make your question clear.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest some commands that may help :

```
WMIC product where "Name LIKE 'Java%%'" call uninstall /nointeractive
WMIC product where "Name LIKE 'J2SE%%'" call uninstall /nointeractive
WMIC product where "Name LIKE 'J2RE%%'" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

These commands need to be run as Admin. They were written
theoretically by me and you should test them very well before
running them on 1600+ Windows computers.

For example, test by using the commands interactively and enter :

```
WMIC product where "Name LIKE 'Java%%'"
```

Note that I have not tested any of these commands, which I leave
up to you to do. Note also that WMIC is slow, and in addition this
only runs the uninstaller for the product and doesn't take care
of any leftovers that the uninstaller might leave behind.

You could also combine these commands from my answer with
the official Java uninstall tool, as the commands might catch
versions that the tool might miss.

Comment: [They claim](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/uninstaller_toolfaq.html) that it removes Java versions from 1.4.2 up so that is every Java version in the last 2 decades. Not sure what kind of errors they got.

Comment: @Gantendo: Yes, if something is missed then this is probably a bug, but WMIC commands can be added for that, once the user identifies what isn't being removed..